# Bootstrap scrollspy offset and smooth animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Html:

```
<div id="mark" class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="/images/newdesk3.jpg" width="60px">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>  

        <div id="t3"><button class="btn btn-warning">Buy Now</button></div>
        <div id="t2"><a href="#oneeye">Technical</a></div>
        <div id="t1"><a href="#similarproducts">Product presentation</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
...
<div id="similarproducts">
...
</div>
<div id="oneeye">
...
</div>
```

jquery offset:

```
 var offset = 80;
$('#t2 a, #t1 a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
        scrollBy(0, -offset);
});
```

jquery smooth animate:

```
$("#t2 a, #t1 a").on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {

      event.preventDefault();      
      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){  

        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }  
  });
```

Jquery offset and smooth animate(scrolling) are working individual as a code but when I put them together are not working.
I use jquery version 1.9.1 with Bootstrap v3.3.5

I need to specify an offset position with animate.
What is the proper code jquery to combine these codes and working properly?

Answer (score 0):

the new jquery code will be

```
$("#t2 a, #t1 a").on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {

      event.preventDefault();      
      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -80
      }, 800, function(){  

        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }  
  });
```